# Imagick from Azure Blob

Tags: php, azure-blob-storage, imagick

I have a PHP site that currently pulls images off an Azure Blob, writes it to disk using file_put_contents, then imagick reads the file from the disk using readImageFile. I would rather this live in memory than be wrote to disk, then read from disk. How can I accomplish this? When I try to ReadImageBlob, I get the below error:

```
Warning: Imagick::readimageblob() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in <file> <line>
```

Below is a snippet of my code (This is just testing code, not production):

```
// Get Data from Azure Storage Blob
$blob = $blobClient->getBlob($containerName, $documentPath);

// Get TIF file from Blob and convert to PDF
$im = new imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($blob->getContentStream());
$im->setImageFormat('pdf');

// Echo as PDF
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $im;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use stream_get_contents to read the string from the stream that you have. Example:

```
$im->readImageBlob(stream_get_contents($blob->getContentStream()));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The stream_get_contents() was the missing piece!

Comment: I just realized something.. Doing this way only shows the last page PDF page for some reason.. So I am going to have to dig into that. I will report back if I figure it out, but feel free to add anything if you already know!

Comment: Never mind.. It was due to me cleaning up my code before posting this. I did a quick google search and found a question I asked months ago.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539023/imagick-php-only-displaying-last-page